# How to show/hide/toggle a div within a form using checkboxes and .next()

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors, toggle

I am trying to toggle a div using jquery - basically want to hide part of a form and only show it when a user selects a particular checkbox.

Now, I have this code below and it works great, but cannot figure out what and where to edit it in order to use with a checkbox rather than a link. Also, I would prefer not to use ID's.

Here is the sample code:

```
.answer { display:none; }

$("a.question").click(function(){
 $(this).next(".answer").toggle();
}); 

<a href="#" class="question">Queston 1</a>
<div class="answer">Answer 1</div>

<a href="#" class="question">Queston 2</a>
<div class="answer">Answer 2</div>
```

Any help at all would be GREATLY APPRECIATED, as this is driving me NUTS!

Comment: Where would the checkboxes be in relation to your code?

Comment: <div class="controls">
                                                                <label><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 1 </label>                                                                <input type="text" class="ShowThis"/>

<label><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 2 </label>                                                                <input type="text" class="ShowThis"/>
                                                                
</div>

Answer (score 4):

```
<label>Question 1:</label><input type="checkbox" class="question"/>
<div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
```

```
$("input[type=checkbox].question").change(function(){
    $(this).next(".answer").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: This works GREAT in a test environment, thank you! Problem is, though, I am developing within the standard Twitter Bootstrap framework, and it just doesn't seem to work within. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
<input class="check" type="checkbox" >
<div class="answer">Answer 1</div>

<input class="check" type="checkbox" >
<div class="answer">Answer 2</div>​
<style type="text/css">
.answer { display:none; }
.check:checked+.answer{
display:block;
}
​
</style>
```

And js is not need.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V9d2W/ 
Browser support for '+' css selector - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: This works GREAT in a test environment, thank you! Problem is, though, I am developing within the standard Twitter Bootstrap framework, and it just doesn't seem to work within. Any suggestions?

Comment: I really like this under-utilized(IMO) solution. But I find myself not using it often because it stops working as soon as you want to move the div somewhere else, that's not directly the next element

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.answer { display:none; }​

<input type="checkbox" class="question" /> : Queston 1
<div class="answer">Answer 1</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="question" /> : Queston 2
<div class="answer">Answer 2</div>​

    $(".question").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).next(".answer").show();
        }
        else{
            $(this).next(".answer").hide();
        }
    });​
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fCarQ/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/h87K2/  : WOrking fiddle

CODE:

```
Queston 1<input type="checkbox" class="question" />
<div class="answer">Answer 1</div>

Queston 2<input type="checkbox" class="question" />
<div class="answer">Answer 2</div>​


$("input.question").click(function(){
 $(this).next(".answer").toggle();
}); 
​
```

Comment: Thanks. This too works GREAT in a test environment, but I am developing within the standard Twitter Bootstrap framework, and it just doesn't seem to work within. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**:

```
.answer { display:none; }​
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="checkbox">Question 1</input>
<div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox">Question 2</input>
<div class="answer">Answer 2</div>​
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function(){
 $(this).next(".answer").toggle();
}); ​
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4HrXY/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Modified code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86eNK/1/)

Html:

```
Queston 1 <input type=checkbox />
<div class="answer">Answer 1</div>

 Queston 2<input type=checkbox />
<div class="answer">Answer 2</div>​
```

JS:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
            $(this).next(".answer").show();
    }
    else{
        $(this).next(".answer").hide();
    }
}); ​
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET:

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="addinfoChk" runat="server" onclick="javascript:OpenPopup(this,'addinfopanel');" />
 <div id="addinfopanel" style="display: none"></div>

<asp:CheckBox ID="addChk" runat="server" onclick="javascript:OpenPopup(this,'addpanel');" />
 <div id="addpanel" style="display: none"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPopup(obj, divid) {
        if (obj.checked == true)
            document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
        else {
            document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

</script>
```